# How to create 2 different linked list and print the intersection of both the linked list

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

```
import java.util.*;
public class Intersection
{
private Node head;
private Node head1;
private Node head2;
private Node current1;
private Node current2;
private int l1;
private int l2;

public Intersection()
{
head= new Node(null);
head1= new Node(null);
head2= new Node(null);
Node current1= head1;
Node current2= head2;
l1=0;l2=0;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
Intersection obj= new Intersection(); 
LinkedList<Object> list1 = new LinkedList<Object>();
LinkedList<Object> list2 = new LinkedList<Object>(); 
list1.add(3);
list1.add(6);
list1.add(9);
list1.add(15);
list1.add(30);
list2.add(10);
list2.add(15);
list2.add(30);
Object ans= obj.method(obj.head1, obj.head2);
System.out.println(ans);
}


public Object method(Node current1, Node current2)
{
int diff;

if(current1== null || current2== null)
{
    return null;
}

while(current1.getNext() != null)
{
   l1++;
   current1=current1.getNext();
}

while(current2.getNext() != null)
{
   l2++;
   current2=current2.getNext();
}

if(l1>l2)
{
    diff=l1-l2;
    int j=0;
    while(j<diff)
    {
        current1=current1.getNext();
        j++;
    }
}

else
{
    diff=l2-l1;
    int j=0;
    while(j<diff)
    {
        current2=current2.getNext();
        j++;
    }
}

 while(current1!= null || current2!= null)
 {
    if(current1.getData()==current2.getData())
        return current1.getData();
    current1=current1.getNext();
    current2=current2.getNext();
}
return null;
}

private class Node
{
Node next;
Object data;

public Node(Object _data)
{
 next= null;
 data= _data;
}

public Node(Node _next, Object _data)
{
next= _next;
data= _data;
}

public Object getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object _data)
    {
        data = _data;
    }

    public Node getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node _next)
    {
        next = _next;
    }
}
}
```

Above is my code to find out the intersection of the linked list in which there is no error.
I am having problem in how to create 2 different linked lists and then print the intersection of the linked list.
Please give some suggestions.

Comment: Why are you implementing your own list instead of using the builtin collection classes? Where is the definition of your `List` class? Where is the declaration of `list1` and `list2`?  It is very hard for anyone to help you with incomplete code. However, posting all your code and saying "please debug this for me" is not acceptable here.  You need to make an effort to figure out what you don't understand and ask a more specific question.

Comment: I have edited my code and now I have declared list1 and list2.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to create LinkedList, where Object is the Type you would hold in your list:

```
LinkedList<Object> list1 = new LinkedList<Object>();
```

to create second LinkedList:

```
 LinkedList<Object> list2 = new LinkedList<Object>();
```

After that you have two lists: list1 and list2,is this what you need?

Intersection:

```
list1.retainAll(list2);
```

and list1 will have the intersection :)

Comment: Ya that's fine......!!!!! I also want to print out the intersection element of the liked list??? So, how should i pass the head node to my public Object method()

Comment: I have just edited my code. It is giving me null as the answer instead of 15. Please give some suggestion why it is going so???

Comment: You should be able to trace the  code and find out why.

Comment: I think my head1 and head2 nodes are null. But I am having a doubt in how to set my head1 as 3 and head2 as 10,